# find the key of songs related to theory of music

Tags: theory

How can we find the key of any song? If we know the key then it might be easy to find the chord progression, but if we don't know whether that particular song is in major or minor or blues then how do we know the chords? So how can I find the key of any song?

Comment: We usually know if a song is in major, minor or blues by listening to what  sort of chords are in the song. I'm pretty sure the other part of the question has been answered before. See the list on the right of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read your comment - When you've found the key note/root note, if the thing's in major, try playing the third note of that particular scale. For example, let's say you find a piece is in C. The third note of that scale is E or Eb. If the E sounds like the last chord, it'll be in C major. If Eb fits better, it'll be C minor.

I hope that's solved what you're looking for, although the majority of players would be aware if it's major or minor as a matter of course.A session with a teacher will sort it out, as we say often on this site!

Answer (score 1):

There is a technical, and a non-technical answer to this question.
Ill do the non-technical one, because I would assume that since you are asking, then you would prefer a simpler less technical answer.
Listen to the song and discover the point in which the song seems to "Resolve".
To use an example.
"London bridge is faling down...falling down , falling down...
London bridge is falling down....( And here you "feel it resolve)
"My fair Lady".... 
The last syllable.."Lady" specifically,the "Dy"... is the tonic or first note , the scale key note you're looking for.
Most songs have this effect. and discovering the note that determines the scale is a similar process. Getting the "Feel" for that resolving note, is only attained with practice. I suggest sitting next to a keyboard and listening to several songs and practicing the process. Eventually it will become second nature, and then the next step is to be able to recognize what the pitch of that note is without the piano! good luck

Comment: Ya sir i can find it by keyboard..bt if the song is on c key..bt how can i find tht its mjor or minor or any scale??by practice i can find this..bt can you plz tell me the technical theroy..or jst point down the step from basic to advance..bcz in youtube..there is lots of theory related to music.like dominant agmented or etc.so i cant find it whts the perfect series to understand music..plzz help me..thanks